# CloudFoundryOperations initialization error

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am trying to use org.cloudfoundry.operations.CloudFoundryOperation to list the instances of the services available on pcf environment. I have cf command line client installed on my laptop and can execute most all 'cf' commands.

While I try to use CloudFoundryOperations to list the services in my org and space on cloud foundry, I am getting following stack trace. It seems that applicaiton is not able to @Autowired the CloudFoundryOperations.
It is hard to debug the reactor code. However, it seems that my problem is with initializing the CloudfoundryOperations with appropriate properties.

The sample code is available at https://github.com/jaysara/pcf-client

```
<pre>
Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$AssemblySnapshotException: null
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly.<init>(MonoOnAssembly.java:62) ~[reactor-core-3.1.6.RELEASE.jar:3.1.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.checkpoint(Mono.java:1367) ~[reactor-core-3.1.6.RELEASE.jar:3.1.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.checkpoint(Mono.java:1317) ~[reactor-core-3.1.6.RELEASE.jar:3.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.cloudfoundry.reactor.tokenprovider.AbstractUaaTokenProvider.token(AbstractUaaTokenProvider.java:271) ~[cloudfoundry-client-reactor-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.cloudfoundry.reactor.tokenprovider.AbstractUaaTokenProvider.getToken(AbstractUaaTokenProvider.java:107) ~[cloudfoundry-client-reactor-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.cloudfoundry.reactor.util.AbstractReactorOperations.addAuthorization(AbstractReactorOperations.java:258) ~[cloudfoundry-client-reactor-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.transform(Mono.java:3553) ~[reactor-core-3.1.6.RELEASE.jar:3.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.cloudfoundry.reactor.util.AbstractReactorOperations.lambda$null$4(AbstractReactorOperations.java:103) ~[cloudfoundry-client-reactor-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
        at reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClient.lambda$handler$4(HttpClient.java:429) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.6.RELEASE.jar:0.7.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.MonoHttpClientResponse$HttpClientHandler.apply(MonoHttpClientResponse.java:119) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.6.RELEASE.jar:0.7.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.MonoHttpClientResponse$HttpClientHandler.apply(MonoHttpClientResponse.java:82) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.6.RELEASE.jar:0.7.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.applyHandler(ChannelOperations.java:380) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.6.RELEASE.jar:0.7.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onHandlerStart(HttpClientOperations.java:501) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.6.RELEASE.jar:0.7.6.RELEASE]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) ~[netty-common-4.1.23.Final.jar:4.1.23.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404) ~[netty-common-4.1.23.Final.jar:4.1.23.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463) ~[netty-transport-4.1.23.Final.jar:4.1.23.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886) [netty-common-4.1.23.Final.jar:4.1.23.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$AssemblySnapshotException: null
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly.<init>(MonoOnAssembly.java:62) ~[reactor-core-3.1.6.RELEASE.jar:3.1.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.checkpoint(Mono.java:1367) ~[reactor-core-3.1.6.RELEASE.jar:3.1.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.checkpoint(Mono.java:1317) ~[reactor-core-3.1.6.RELEASE.jar:3.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.cloudfoundry.reactor.tokenprovider.AbstractUaaTokenProvider.token(AbstractUaaTokenProvider.java:271) ~[cloudfoundry-client-reactor-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.cloudfoundry.reactor.tokenprovider.AbstractUaaTokenProvider.getToken(AbstractUaaTokenProvider.java:107) ~[cloudfoundry-client-reactor-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.cloudfoundry.reactor.util.AbstractReactorOperations.addAuthorization(AbstractReactorOperations.java:258) ~[cloudfoundry-client-reactor-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.transform(Mono.java:3553) ~[reactor-core-3.1.6.RELEASE.jar:3.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.cloudfoundry.reactor.util.AbstractReactorOperations.lambda$null$4(AbstractReactorOperations.java:103) ~[cloudfoundry-client-reactor-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
        at reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClient.lambda$handler$4(HttpClient.java:429) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.6.RELEASE.jar:0.7.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.MonoHttpClientResponse$HttpClientHandler.apply(MonoHttpClientResponse.java:119) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.6.RELEASE.jar:0.7.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.MonoHttpClientResponse$HttpClientHandler.apply(MonoHttpClientResponse.java:82) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.6.RELEASE.jar:0.7.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.applyHandler(ChannelOperations.java:380) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.6.RELEASE.jar:0.7.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onHandlerStart(HttpClientOperations.java:501) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.6.RELEASE.jar:0.7.6.RELEASE]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) ~[netty-common-4.1.23.Final.jar:4.1.23.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404) ~[netty-common-4.1.23.Final.jar:4.1.23.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463) ~[netty-transport-4.1.23.Final.jar:4.1.23.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886) [netty-common-4.1.23.Final.jar:4.1.23.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
</pre>
```

The gradle file dependancies configurattion is as followed.

```
<pre>
ext {
    springCloudVersion = 'Finchley.M9'
}
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-commons')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-discovery')
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-dependencies:2.0.0.M3'
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('io.projectreactor:reactor-test')
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-dependencies:2.0.0.M3"
    }
</pre>
```